# How to detect whether an object is ready in JS?

Tags: javascript, object, activex, controls

My web app includes an ActiveX control. However, when I run the app, I got error "object expected" error intermittently. It seems sometimes the control is not ready when I call its properties/methods. Is there a way that I can detect whether an object is ready using JS?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If its not you own app, see if you can identify some harmless property or method and then design a wrapper method around the call that tests with try catch if it can access the object, and if yes, call next method in chain (maybe using a delegate to include arguments, and if not ready, use setTimeout to call the wrapper again in say 100 ms.

You might want to include a retry counter to bailout after a few tries so that it's not an infinite loop if the object is broken.

Example:

```
function TryCallObject(delegate, maxtries, timebetweencalls, failCallback, retrycount)
{
    if(typeof retrycount == "undefined")
        retrycount = 0;
    if(typeof failCallback == "undefined")
        failCallback null;
    try {
        //code to do something harmless to detect if objects is ready
        delegate(); //If we get here, the object is alive
    } catch(ex) {
        if(retrycount >= maxtries)
        {
             if(failCallback != null)
                  failCallback();
             return;
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
              TryCallObject(delegate, maxtries, timebetweencalls, failCallback, retryCount + 1);
            }, timebetweencalls);
    }
}
```

And its called like this

```
TryCallObject(function() { /* your code here */ }, 5, 100);
```

or

```
TryCallObject(function() { /* your code here */ }, 5, 100, function() {alert("Failed to access ActiveX");});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer David. I was able to catch the error using your way but keep increasing timeout didn't solve the issue. We ended remove <table></table> and used <div> which is faster to load.

Comment: Ok, was it a table that was rendered that caused the delay?

Answer (score 0):

If it is your own app, include a readystate event

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751970%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The way we do this in FireBreath (http://firebreath.org) is to fire an event to javascript; it does this by providing a function name in a <param> tag, get a reference to the browser window IDispatch pointer, and do a PROPERTYGET for the function named in the param tag.

We then call that method when the plugin is ready to go. This has the advantage of working pretty much the same way in all browsers, since FireBreath plugins work both as ActiveX controls and NPAPI Plugins.